# removing newline character after split command

Tags: perl, split

I have a file that has timestamps in format like 10:24:23
what I am trying to do is split these timestamps but remove the new line characters after the split.  The desired output I want is 102423, however what I am currently getting is:
10\n24\n23\n

this is the script I am running:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $cmd = `cat test.txt |awk {'print \$2')`;
my @array = $cmd;

my @values = split(':', $cmd);
print @values;

for (@values) {
    chomp $_;
    if ($_ == 102423) {
        print "Hello\n";
    }
}
```

---

when I print out the @values array I see what I want, '102423'
however when I attempt an `if` comparison I get an error saying that my variable is not numeric. The error shows like this: "10\n24\n23 is not numeric"

thanks for taking the time
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you get all the timestamps, then split them on colons, which creates invalid values: seconds + newline + hours of the following timestamp.

Process the file line by line. No need to call `awk` from Perl. Open the file and use `(split)[1]` to get the second column (and remove the trailing newline).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $IN, '<', 'test.txt' or die $!;  # Open the file.
while (<$IN>) {                          # Process it line by line.
    my $timestamp = (split)[1];          # Get the second column.
    $timestamp =~ tr/://d;               # Remove colons.
    if (102423 == $timestamp) {
        print "Hello\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: now what I have to do is compare the first two timestamps in the array to see how many seconds have elapsed between the two log lines.

example:
line one of array: 102423
line two of array: 102425

for (@array) {
if ($_ + 5 <= line two of array) {
print "AHHH BRUTEFORCE"
}
}

I dont expect to be spoon fed I am fine with doing the reading myself, but some guidance would be appreciated, as I am new to perl.
c

Comment: @user3821215: That complicates the situation a lot. You should rather start a new question.