# Comparing elements in an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I am working on writing a script that identifies login attempts that are 5 seconds or less apart, searching for brute force login attempts. So far I have been able to take the log timestamps and convert them to a readable and workable format, by using the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $IN, '<', 'test.txt' or die $!;  # Open the file.
while (<$IN>) {                          # Process it line by line.
    my $timestamp = (split)[1];          # Get the second column.
    $timestamp =~ tr/://d;               # Remove colons.
    print "$timestamp\n";
}
```

The output I get looks like

```
102432
102434
104240
```

etc.

What I want to do is compare the numbers in the array to see if there is a five-second delay or less between login attempts. Something like:

```
if ($timestamp + 5 <= 2nd element in array) {
   print "ahhh brute force"
}
```

The same thing all the way down the array elements until the end.

```
if (2nd element in array + 5 <= 3rd element in array) {
   print "ahh brute force"
}
```

etc.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Example of input:

```
2014-08-10      13:20:30        GET     Portal/jsjquery-latest.js  404     -       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your input file?

Comment: Note that timestamp + 5 is wrong for seconds > 54.

Comment: Save `$timestamp` to `$timestamp_old` and compare these two on each iteration?

Comment: I edited the post and added a sample log line, as requested

Comment: I'm afraid you have started from the wrong place: your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25495374) doesn't get you to a more useful place as you can't just concatenate the time fields and treat them as a number. You will also need the date so that you can subtract times that span a midnight. Presumably the date is in the log too? We can't help you unless you show the format of a log record.

Comment: well not exactly, what is the format of your timestamp? 24h or 12h based? Leading zeros?

Comment: yes its a 24 hour timestamp, sample of it is added in the original post.

Comment: @user3821215 Use a module designed to compare times and dates and you will save yourself a lot of trouble and potential bugs.

Answer (score 2):

This will do as you ask. It uses [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece), which has been a core module since version 10 of Perl 5, and so shouldn't need installing.

It uses both the date and the time fields from the log file to build `Time::Piece` objects, which can then be subtracted from one another to calculate the intervals.

The program expects the path to the log file as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $last_login;

while (<>) {
   my @login = split;
   my $login = Time::Piece->strptime("@login[0,1]", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

   if ($last_login) {
      my $interval = $login - $last_login;
      if ($interval <= 5) {
         printf "%s to %s is %d seconds\n", $last_login, $login, $interval;
      }
   }

   $last_login = $login;
}
```

---

**Update**

As `@knarf` says in a comment, this can be done using a regular expression together with the [`Time::Local`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Local) module's `timelocal` function.

This is a program that does something similar using that technique.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Local 'timelocal';

my $last_login;

while (<>) {
   next unless my @login = / (\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d) \s+ (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) /x;
   $login[0] -= 1900;
   $login[1] -= 1;
   my $login = timelocal reverse @login;

   if ($last_login) {
      my $interval = $login - $last_login;
      if ($interval <= 5) {
         printf "%s to %s is %d seconds\n", map(scalar localtime $_, $last_login, $login), $interval;
      }
   }

   $last_login = $login;
}
```

Comment: you can use `timelocal` from the Time::Local module if Time::Piece is not available.

    `m/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/;
    my $login = timelocal($6, $5, $4, $3, $2, $1);`

Comment: hey knarf, could you please elaborate more? if you were to use timelocal how would the code change? I understand the fields $6 $5 etc... however im not sure where you would put the REGEX? could just edit borodin's code to show how it would work with timelocal?

cheers.

Comment: @user3821215: Since you've shown an interest in a solution using `Time::Local` instead of `Time::Piece`, I've added to my answer to show you how it could be done; but in my opinion it's not such a clean solution. Do you have a problem with using `Time::Piece`?

Comment: yeah the perl interpreter is old on the server im running it on, and it doesnt like Time:Piece,

question though, I ran you above code and the month is off, its saying "Sept 25" should be Aug.25

Comment: @user3821215: Okay thanks, I've fixed that. I overlooked that `timelocal` expects a zero-based month number. Also the year should be relative to 1900 like the `localtime` return value, but it seems to accept either that or the actual year.